# How to Display my object properly if it has a few parameters through linkedlist

Tags: c#

i'm kind of new to C# and i need some help regarding my assignment.
First off, i have to display a linkedlist containing an Object called `Parcel` and that `Parcel`
contains a few parameters `int id`, `string name`, `int weight`. When try to call a function to display whatever is inside the linkedlist, i get an error.

here is my `DisplayInventory()` function :

```
public void DisplayInventory()
    {

        for (Node j = head; j != null; j = j.Link )
        {

           Console.WriteLine(j.Data);

        }
    }
```

Here is my parcel class :

```
class Parcel

    private int id;
    private String customerName;
    private int weight;

    public Parcel(int id, String customerName, int weight) 
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.customerName = customerName;
        this.weight = weight;
    }
    public int ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set { id = value; }
    }
    public String CustomerName
    {
        get { return customerName; }
        set { customerName = value; }
    }
    public int Weight 
    {
        get { return weight; }
        set { weight = value; }
    }
}
```

And here is my Node Class :

```
class Node
{
    private object data;

    public object Data
    {
        get { return data; }
        set { data = value; }
    }
    private Node link;

    internal Node Link
    {
        get { return link; }
        set { link = value; }
    }

    public Node(object d)
    {
        this.data = d;
    }
}
```

Everything runs fine except for my DisplayInventory() function found in my linkedlist.cs. It just displayed `AppName.Parcel` when i tried to print it out, i know i have to cast my j.data, but it doesn't work for me, any help? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm assuming you have to actually implement a linked list and can't use `LinkedList<T>` (part of the framework)

Comment: "it doesn't work"  What does, "it doesn't work" mean?  Does it just print out the class's name rather than the properties, does it throw an exception, does it not print anything, does it not compile, or what?  You need to be specific about what's not working.

Comment: @Charleh Yes , i did implement my own linkedlist.

Comment: @Servy It just prints out AppName.Parcel , and everything runs fine with no errors.

Answer (score 1):

You should print each property instead:

```
Console.WriteLine("Id: " + j.Data.Id.ToString());
Console.WriteLine("Name: " + j.Data.Name);
```

and so on.

Comment: Thanks again, but now i have another problem, it doesn't point to ID when i tried.

Answer (score 1):

`Console.WriteLine` will call `object.ToString()` on your `j.Data` object which by default just returns the type name (Parcel).

I'm assuming `DisplayInventory` is inside the class which is implementing the linked list - in which case you should be able to refer to the properties of the class directly:

e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(j.Id);
```

You could also override `ToString` on whatever `j` is (Parcel) by adding this to the source:

```
public override string ToString() { return this.Id.ToString(); }
```

Edit:

Ok in light of your update, you can just cast `Node.Data` (j.Data) to Parcel and access members directly:

```
for (Node j = head; j != null; j = j.Link )
{
    // Cast using the as keyword - if the cast fails, parcel will be null, otherwise it will be the casted object
    var parcel = j.Data as Parcel;

    // Check if parcel is null, if not write some info
    if(parcel != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(parcel.Id);
        Console.WriteLine(parcel.CustomerName);  // etc
    }
}
```

Alternatively - just use `j.Data.ToString()` and ensure you have overridden the `ToString` member for `Parcel`

e.g. in `Parcel.cs`

```
// Override the ToString method. If you are using Visual Studio you should get a popup
// telling you which methods you can override after you type override then hit space
public override string ToString() 
{
    // string.format is one way of formatting the data, the tokens are replaced by the indexed arguments
    return string.Format("{0} - {1}", Id, CustomerName);
}
```

Comment: i got an error when i tried to do Console.WriteLine(j.ID);

 error CS1061: 'Node' does not contain a definition for 'ID' and no extension method 'ID' accepting a first argument of type 'Node' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Sounds like your `Parcel` class isn't the one implementing `DisplayInventory`, so I assume it's the linked list implementation and that `Data` is the container for each list item. In that case just use `Console.WriteLine(((Parcel)j).Id);` to cast

Comment: @ongdingchao I think it should be `j.Data.ID` but for more correct answer we need your `Node` and `Parcel` classes

Comment: Alright, thanks again, but now i have another error : 
error CS0030: Cannot convert type 'Node' to 'EveryThingCanPackApp.Parcel'

Comment: Sorry yes I meant `j.Data` - so `Console.WriteLine(((Parcel)j.Data).Id);`. It might be useful to post your full program

Comment: @ongdingchao add please your `Node` and `Parcel` implementation

Comment: @Charleh  i have added my Node and Parcel classes.

Comment: @GuruStron i have added both classes.

Comment: but overriding of `ToString()` method would be more elegant solution

Comment: Alright, thanks guys it worked, but can you explain to me briefly why it didn't work, i have to comment on every line, and it would help me greatly if i understood why.

Comment: @GuruStron i'm new to C# so i don't know hw to override methods, i'm afraid that i will screw up even more.

Comment: your `Data` is `object` type so it doesn't have `ID` propety, but you know that it's really `Parcel` so you cast it with `(Parcel)` and can access `ID`. An first variant haven't worked because in `c#` every object is derived from 'Object' class wich has `ToString()` method, but to make it work properly for your class you should override it

Comment: @ongdingchao if you're familiar with inheritance and virtual methods concept you can read [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3(v=vs.71).aspx) about `override` keyword.

Comment: @GuruStron ohh, so if i override the ToString() method it would work the same just that it is more efficient?

Comment: `ToString` is a virtual method declared on `object`. Since all classes in .NET derive from `object` you can call `ToString` on any class. Because it's virtual, if you override the method in a sub-class, the most derived method is always called, therefore `ToString` on `object` actually makes a virtual method call to `ToString` on `Parcel` even though at compile-time it doesn't know the most derived type of the object. Casting ensures that you are dealing with a more derived type rather than a super type - you cast, then you can be sure you are accessing methods/props that actually exist

Comment: @Charleh Ah...Thanks alot charleh, because C# seems similar to C++ but because C# involves objects and classes just like in C++ i get confused alot. Thanks again.

Comment: @Charleh And erm, if i may, can i ask you one last question before i go off. I have to do one last function and it's named SortByCustomerName():  This method will sort the linked list by the customer name in ascending order.
Do i need to compare every single CustomerName before i print them out? or does C# has a function that lets me do it.

Comment: Yes C# has a type that handles this, and it also has a type that implements a linked list - however, if this is for an assignment, then you will likely get better marks for sorting the list yourself. Whichever way you look at it - you need to at visit each item in the list at least once in order to get the customername and provide an ordered index, so in short, yes you do need to compare them all whether it be by framework functionality or manual sorting algorithm.

Comment: @Charleh Because the assignment doesn't allow me to use Arrays at all, and other than that i have been racking my brains and googling for different ways to do it , but to no avail, what do you recommend me to do? Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can call `Console.WriteLine()` for each field/property of your `Parcel` class or override it's `ToString()` method. It would look like that:

```
public class Parcel()
{
    public override string ToString()
    {  
         string str =  ....// create here your string representation of Parcel
         // if number of fileds is quite big use StringBuilder class
         return str;
    }
}
```